# Sequencing of projects in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

In cruisecontrol.net I have three projects, A, B and C that needs to be built in sequence. A must be built before B, and B before C. I get this to mostly work by using a project trigger on B that watches project A and a project trigger on C that watches B. (I use multipleTrigges with projectTrigger and intervalTrigger on project B and C)

When A builds it “resets” everything, so B must be built before building C. But every now and then changes in the source control system triggers a build in C before B is build, with a failed compile as result. How can I avoid that case?
One idea is that A modifies the build status of B from “Success” to “Undefined”, but I have not found a way to do this.

Any (other) ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the project trigger interval to 1 or 2 seconds (it's 5 by default) and the intervaltrigger to 120 seconds, thus your problem should be less frequent.

You can also put your three projects in a single queue to avoid building B and C in parallel. Setting the queue priorities can help ordering your projects too.